# How to convert latitude/longitude in degrees to BBOX where SRS=EPSG:27700

Tags: geospatial, wms

Anyone know how to convert latitude, longitude in degrees to define a `BBOX` where `SRS=EPSG:27700`?

I am trying to call a WMS service with a URL like following (not a real link):
http://mysecretmappingserver.com/wms?user=myuser&pwd=mypassword&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=ap25cm&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:27700&BBOX=229096,231675,229296,231875&width=400&height=400

<strike>Any language would be fine; C# preferable.</strike>

Spacedman has been trying to help me, but I can't seem to get Proj4Net to work for me - all me, I'm sure - but if someone knows either Proj4Net or the math involved, that might be better...

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does the url you give above not work? Or are you trying to ask the service for that bbox in lat long?

Comment: The URL above works fine, but I need to translate arbitrary lat/lng's to EPSG:27700 for the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an interface to the PROJ.4 projections library in your language of choice. In R, for example, its in the rgdal package:

Here's some points (1,1 to 2,2 degrees)  in epsg:4326:

```
> pts
SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]         1         1
[2,]         2         2
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:4326
```

and voila:

```
> spTransform(pts,CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]  734005.9  -5416918
[2,]  845270.7  -5305999
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:27700
```

Proj.4 docs here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

Since this is OSGB, probably a better example would be in the UK: here's a point in central london:

```
> pts = SpatialPoints(cbind(-0.109863,51.460852),proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
> spTransform(pts,CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]  531407.1  175235.8
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:27700
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000
+y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs
+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with Proj4Net, but obviously doing something wrong.  With EPSG:4326 => EPSG:27700 I get [1, 1] -> [73415123.9660797, -99688949.1195301]  Src CRS: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
Tgt CRS: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to try it on points waaay outside the UK. Try with my London example I edited into my answer.

Comment: Still not getting the same results as you:  WGS84 => EPSG:27700
[-0.109863, 51.460852] -> [107964.802048213, -13603338.2322458] 
Src CRS: +title=long/lat:WGS84 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees 
Tgt CRS: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `ogr2ogr`, which among other things can convert between projections. I have it installed on my Mac, and there are binding e.g. to Python and many other languages. You can also use it on the commandline. Homepage is http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: OGR/GDAL contains Proj.4, so this is similar to the other answer.